# Canvas bouncing balls showing an elliptical black ball

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/km6ozj6L/)**

**Intended behavior**

Sample values: Velocity: 10; Angle: 45; Color: red; Radius: 50.

On clicking "Shoot!" button, ball should move until it finally disappears behind one of the walls.  Note that I want to simulate real world ball with gravity.

Each time we click Shoot, one more ball should be added to the `balls` array which will also be drawn.

**What happens**

A black ellipse is shown on clicking shoot once/multiple time. No console errors seen.

[image: problem image]

**Code:**

```
(function () {
    var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
        WIDTH = canvas.width,
        HEIGHT = canvas.height;

    // our ball object
    function Ball(radius, color) {
        this.radius = radius;
        this.color = color;
        this.x = 50; // start coordinates
        this.y = 50;
        this.velX = 0;
        this.velY = 0;
        this.accX = 0;
        this.accY = 0;
        this.gravity = 0;

        this.start = function (angle, velocity) {
            this.gravity = 9.8;
            this.angle = angle / 180 * Math.PI; // convert to radians
            this.velX = velocity * Math.cos(this.angle);
            this.velY = velocity * Math.sin(this.angle);
            this.accX = 0; // zero intially
            this.accY = 0; // TODO: set option for user to set himself
        };

        this.update = function () {
            this.velY -= this.gravity;
        };

        this.draw = function () {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.fillSyle = this.color;
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();
        }
    }

    // balls array
    var balls = [];

    document.querySelector("input[type='button']").onclick = function () {
        var color = gId("color").value,  // getElementById; defined in jsfiddle
            velocity = gId("velocity").value,
            angle = gId("angle").value,
            radius = gId("radius").value;

        var ball = new Ball(radius, color);
        ball.start(angle, velocity);
        balls.push(ball);
    };

    setInterval(function () {
        for (var i = 0, len = balls.length; i < len; i++) {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            balls[i].draw();
            balls[i].update();
        }
    }, 1000 / 60); // 1000/x depicts x fps
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work. System: Windows 7 on Chrome/Firefox latest.

Any help is appreciated. Please comment for more information.

Comment: The update method of your balls doesn't change the position. Which might relate to the balls not moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Set width and height attributes on your canvas element instead of applying a css style i.e:

```
    <canvas width="400px" height="400px">You don't support canvas.</canvas>
```

2) divide the value of gravity by 60 because your update function is invoked every 1/60th of a second i.e:

```
    this.start = function (angle, velocity) {
        this.gravity = 9.8 / 60;
        this.angle = angle / 180 * Math.PI; // convert to radians
        this.velX = velocity * Math.cos(this.angle);
        this.velY = velocity * Math.sin(this.angle);
        this.accX = 0; // zero intially
        this.accY = 0; // TODO: set option for user to set himself
    };
```

3) change the update function to:

```
    this.update = function () {
        this.velY += this.gravity;
        this.x += this.velX;
        this.y += this.velY;
    };
```

4) move the ctx.clearRect method outside the for loop otherwise you will only see one ball animating always i.e

```
setInterval(function () {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    for (var i = 0, len = balls.length; i < len; i++) {            
        balls[i].draw();
        balls[i].update();
    }
}, 1000 / 60); // 1000/x depicts x fps
```

Here the updated js-fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/km6ozj6L/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot! Still though, a black ball is shown. How do I fix that?

Comment: there was a typo it is ctx.fillStyle not ctx.fillSyle heres the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/km6ozj6L/2/